# If a Cauchy sequence contains a convergent subsequence, must the Cauchy sequence have the same limit?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space with norm $\|\cdot\|$. Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$ containing a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ which converges to some $x \in X$.

Is it true that $(x_n)$ must also converge to $x$?

I think the answer is yes, since $$\|x_n - x\| \leq \|x_n - x_{n_k}\| + \|x_{n_k} - x\| < \epsilon,$$ but I would appreciate any verification/correction.

Comment: For sake of contradiction, what if it didn't?

Comment: One thing seems pretty clear: if it *does* converge, then it converges to $x$.

Comment: @JohnHughes well, $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in a complete space, so it must converge